# Getting error Uninitialized ASN.1 value when trying to use pympler.tracker.SummaryTracker()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a memory leak in my python2.7 code and I'm trying to debug it using `pympler`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eta/dynamic_eta_worker.py", line 29, in <module>
    tr = tracker.SummaryTracker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pympler/tracker.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.s0 = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pympler/summary.py", line 131, in summarize
    total_size[otype] = _getsizeof(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 145, in plug
    raise error.PyAsn1Error('Uninitialized ASN.1 value ("%s" attribute looked up)' % name)
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Uninitialized ASN.1 value ("__sizeof__" attribute looked up)
```

Tried to search here and in google and came out with nothing.
The thing is that when I call `pympler.tracker.SummaryTracker()` from the python console it works like a charm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U pyasn1
```

please try to upgrade pyasn1 version